# The float representations of a constant and a variable are different?

Tags: c++, floating-point, constants, variable-assignment

I executed the following C++ code and get the answer "Not the same? Weird.....". Originally I expected to get "Of course, they are the same!!!". I was using Dev-C++ 5.11.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float p;
    p = 0.3;
    if ((p-0.3)==0)
        cout << "Of course, they are the same !!!\n";
    else
        cout << "Not the same? Weird.....\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0.3` is a double not a float

Comment: Note that 0.3 is not exactly representable in neither single nor double precision IEEE 754 format. You can try it, for example, here: https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point.

Answer (score 1):

As Mat points out, the problem here is that `0.3` is a double. And `(double)(float)0.3 != 0.3`. You lose precision when casting `0.3` to float. Casting it back does not magically undo the rounding.

Comment: And that's why this question isn't really a duplicate of the one it was closed against.